# How can Deep Q Learning be applied to scenarios with rewards only received in a final step?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am applying DQ Learning to a continuous action space with rewards received at the end of each trial. My agent is in a fixed 24step long setting where it receives the reward at the end of those 24 steps.

DQ Learning uses experience replay and randomly samples out of these areas. That would mean that if I placed all these actions into my replay buffer, the agent would learn 23/24 times that whatever action it takes, the reward is 0. And then it would associate whatever action it took in the last of the 24 steps as the rewarding action. However, that is not at all what I want to learn.

So, can it be that the DQN learning approach dissolved the idea of the agent being successfully considering "expected future reward" in its policy updates? Or did I misinterpret DQN learning?

I read the typical papers on this:

- Original DQ by DeepMind on Atari https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5602
- Continuous DeepQ with NAF http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/gu16.pdf
- Continuous control with DQL: https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02971

All of those play Atari games and I believe they continuously receive a reward, so they can just randomly sample an state-action-rew-state tuple because they get a reward for almost all actions (more or less).

Answer (score 2):

> the agent would learn 23/24 times that whatever action it takes, the
>   reward is 0

The Q-function maps a state-action pair to the *expected discounted cumulative future reward*, not the immediate reward of taking an action. Therefore it's perfectly fine to run Q-learning with sparse rewards. (It can be problematic for other reasons though).

Comment: how can the agent expect a future reward, if the transition has never been observed together with the following transitions that actually lead to the reward? How does the expected future reward get passed form the final step to the first step if experience replay doesn't sample across whole trajectories but just across single S-A-R-S tuples?

Comment: @pascalwhoop the reward gets "passed" backwards due to the way the Q-function is recursively defined using future states. Look at the loss function for Q-learning.

Comment: @pascalwhoop: Initially, when the agent runs its first few episodes, your intuition that the agent cannot possibly know is correct. In fact this is one of the factors related to problems with stability of Q-learning algorithm and neural networks. However, once the agent learns where to find at least some better immediate rewards and the transitions that lead to them, using them in experience replay, then the updates to the estimate for Q will do as shimao says and feed back to improved estimates of future reward in earlier states.

Comment: @NeilSlater I could adapt the reward function a bit to give it a reward also "on the way" I believe that will largely outperform the alternative approach.

Comment: @pascalwhoop: I would advise against meddling with the reward scheme.  Essentially by doing this you are inserting your own "expert" heuristics or prior knowledge for the agent. There may be better approaches for sparse reward schemes - e.g. prioritised sweeping for planning, or TD($\lambda$) to update more of each trajectory at once in Q learning. Although it depends what your purpose is?

Comment: @NeilSlater I'm having the very same problem. My reward comes at the end of episode, 10 transitions after I apply action to state. I'm using DQN but my model is not learning and I've tried all sorts of shenanigans. Can you elaborate on your approaches?

Comment: @d9ngle: Not in the comments I cannot. Rewards at ends of episodes are a common occurence in RL. As a first guess, it is possible that you are missing state related to the delayed reward - if the reward is directly keyed to an action taken 10 steps before, it is important that action makes some change to the state representation in order for the MDP model of the environment to have the Markov property. If that is not the issue, or you cannot figure it out from my brief comment here, you might want to ask a new question on the site, and give details about your problem.

Comment: @NeilSlater I have two input which show the action has been taken (action_space {0 = do_nothing, 1 = act }). one is a cool down timer in seconds and the other is can_action_be_taken flag which should be enough. My network is also not respecting the flag so I started giving it huge_penalty when coming up with invalid action but then the network would over-fit and only give 0, and I tried just discarding invalid actions from network but still model doesn't learn.

Comment: @d9ngle: Not enough room to discuss you project here. If you want someone to look in detail at it, I suggest you ask a question here, or in AI Stack Exchange.